# AngularJS Jasmine spy provided factory and callthrough

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to provide my own function to replace a factory, and I also want the ability to use `.and.callThrough()` to use the original functionality. The main problem I'm running into is that I can't inject a factory in to the mock module statement.

```
describe("It", function() {
    var mockFactory;

    //This works, but the original functionality is gone at this point because I'm overriding it with $provide
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule', function($provide) {
        mockFactory = jasmine.createSpy('myFactory');
        $provide.factory('myFactory', function() { return mockFactory });
    }));

    //This fails because I cant inject the actual factory into the module mock
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule', function($provide, myFactory) {
        mockFactory = jasmine.createSpy('myFactory', myFactory);
        $provide.factory('myFactory', function() { return mockFactory });
    }));

})
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `$provide.decorator()` like this:

```
describe('It', function() {
   var mockFactory;

   beforeEach(module('myModule', function ($provide) {
     $provide.decorator('myFactory', function ($delegate) {
       mockFactory = jasmine.createSpy('myFactory', $delegate).and.callThrough();
       return mockFactory;
     });
   }));

   it('should call through', function () {
     mockFactory('foo', 'bar');
     expect(myFactory).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My factory does not have methods, it returns a function.  `.factory('myFactory', function() { return function() { ... }; })`

Comment: Ok I'll give this a try. Can you explain this $delegate magic?

Comment: Thanks! That worked!! https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator

Comment: Glad I could help : ) I think the decorator is a little-known feature that is useful especially for testing or injecting test data during development.